# Private azure file share mounted automatically for AD users

Tags: azure-files, azure-storage-account, azure-storage-files

I am wondering if its possible to have a file share mounted automatically to a particular VM  for a particular user?

for example, lets say I have a file share `fs1`  and a windows server VM named `VM1`. VM1 has following user accounts `user1` and `user2`.

for the above configuration, is it possible to mount fs1 exclusively to `user1` automatically when user logs in? Also, unmount as soon as he logs out. Reason for log out is so that if `user2` logs in, i can mount the same fileshare `fs1` to `user2`. But, possibly having different restrictions based on the user.

Comment: File shares are mounted per user, The option what you are looking isn't possible! You could use a group policy to auto-mount the file share

Note: They need to use AD DS auth for this to work, If you are using the storage account key, it will not work

Answer (score 0):

File shares are mounted per user, The option what you are looking isn't possible! You could use a group policy to auto-mount the file share Note: They need to use AD DS auth for this to work, If you are using the storage account key, it will not work